# Animation issue using Processing 2.0 Java

Tags: java, animation, processing

I came across an issue while working on Processing 2.0 software using Java.
Each time I add an animation, I also add a background to erase the previous frame of this animation.
Unfortunately, this process also erases the rest of my graphics.
Is there a way to animate PShape without adding a new background?
Or is there a better way to animate shape in general?
I also would like to mention that I work with ActionScript language and my understanding of animation is based around MovieClip.

Thanks.

EDIT: Code added below:

Application Entry point

```
LineManager lineManager;
Character character;

void setup() {
  size( 300, 600 );
  background( 50 );
  rectMode( CENTER );
  frameRate( 24 );
  lineManager = new LineManager();
  character   = new Character();
}

void draw() {
  character.onTick();
}
```

Character Class

```
public class Character {

  float MIN_VALUE = 80;
  float value     = MIN_VALUE;

  float radius = 50.0;
  int X, Y;
  int nX, nY;
  int delay = 16;

  PShape player;

  public Character() {
    X = width / 2;
    Y = height / 2;
    nX = X;
    nY = Y;  

    player  = loadShape("player.svg");
  } 

  public void onTick() {
    value = value + sin( frameCount/4 );

    X += (nX-X)/delay;
    Y += (nY-Y)/delay;

    /*
    **  My issue is the line below, as when adding it to render the animation
    **  I end up hiding the rest of my graphics
    */ 
    background(0);
    ellipse( X, Y, value, value );  
    shape( player, -10, 140, 320, 320 );
    fill( 222, 222, 222, 222 );
  }
}
```

Comment: post along with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Processing dialect doesn't support indipendent **graphics layers**, but there are plenty of third party libraries that enable you to do that, like [this one (last update: 2011)](http://nootropicdesign.com/processing-layers/).

Check out the updated list of the main libraries on [Processing's site](http://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/), under the *Animation* section.